# ToggleMe Script minor issue

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a working toggle me code except for one small issue and I am not sure what to do to fix it. Can some one please help me. I have duplicated the code in jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/ydvuN/10/

Issue: If you click on Tab 1 or Tab 3 as your initial click, then the menu hides and then you must click on Tab 2 in order for it to show back up. After the initial click the script works like it should, switching between the tabs showing and hiding the menus appropriately.

Now, reload the page and click on Tab 2 as your initial click, the menu works like it should right off the bat, toggling between the different tabs showing their appropriate menus.

I don't ever want to hide the menu completely... I always want one menu to show at all times, however never want more than one menu to show.  The menus should toggle with each other no matter what Tab you click on first.

I understand that this may be happening because I have `display: none` on Tab 1 and Tab 3 and a `display: block` on Tab 2. I did this because I want Tab 2 to display as the default when the page loads.

Any help on correcting my issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Please include your actual code in the question. fiddles are useful, but should be *in addition* to the information that's in the question, not actually required to understand the questions.

Comment: Try using the `visibility` property instead of `display`: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Comment: @Alfie, no - visibility leaves the element in the document flow, and will mess up the positioning of the various tabs.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. By the way, I don't think you need to set the display property of mh to `block` for it to be visible by default. Try ommiting `display: block;` from the css for `#topmenu #mf `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.style.display` is different from just checking whether the item is displayed. It's actually checking the `style="something"` attribute on the HTML - which overrides the CSS you've setup in the stylesheet.

So - when you start out, your elements do **not** have `style.display = 'none'`. In fact, `style.display` is not set.

To solve this, I'd just set the selected tab to `style.display='block'` regardless of what it's already set to:

```
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < allIds.length; i++) {
        if (allIds[i] != a) {
            document.getElementById(allIds[i]).style.display="none";
        }
    }
    e.style.display="block";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly! I knew it had to be something simple I was missing.  Thanks for pointing this out for me.